# Highlight correct answer in bold and red in task environment

Tags: exam

I am working on multiple choice question paper and I want to know is there something similar to \correctchoice in task environment? My objective is when I use **\printanswers**, the correct option of every question is highlighted in bold font and red color. How can I achieve it?

```
\documentclass[a4peper,12pt,addpoints]{exam}
\date{}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage[top=0.6in, bottom=1in, left=0.6in, right=0.55in]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancybox}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{tasks}
\usepackage{mathpazo}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}
\usepackage{anyfontsize}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage[ddmmyyyy]{datetime}
\usepackage{multicol,adjustbox}
\usepackage{cellspace}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage{color, colortbl}
\title{\vspace{-1.6cm}\bfseries\huge \fbox{\fbox{DAILY PRACTICE PROBLEM}} \\[3mm]
    \Large  \fbox{XYZ}\\[5mm] \hline\hline \vspace{0.3 cm}
    \normalsize  MM: 50 \hfill Duration : 30 minutes \hfill  DPP 1 \vspace{0.3 cm} \hline \hline
}
\settasks{label=(\Alph*), label-width=2em}
\renewcommand{\solutiontitle}{\noindent\textbf{Answer:}\enspace}
\SolutionEmphasis{\color{red}}

%\printanswers


\begin{document}
\maketitle

\vspace{-2.8 cm}

\begin{center}

 \subsection*{\Large{IMPORTANT INSTRUCTIONS}}   
\end{center}
\rule[2ex]{\textwidth}{2pt}
\begin{enumerate}\singlespacing \small
 \item Section A contains TEN objective type question having only one option correct. Each question carries $4$ marks.
 \item  Section B contains FIVE True/False questions. Each question carries $2$ marks.
 \item In section A, $4$ marks will be awarded for marking correct answer, $-1$ for marking incorrect answer and $0$ marks for not marking the answer.
 \item There is no negative marking in section B .

\end{enumerate}
\rule[2ex]{\textwidth}{1.5pt}

{ \fontsize{12}{14.4}\selectfont
\begin{center}
\cellwidth{0.3cm}
\hqword{\textbf{Question:}}
\hpword{\textbf{Marks Allotted:}}
\hsword{\textbf{Marks Obtained:}}
\gradetable[h][questions]
\end{center}
\rule[2ex]{\textwidth}{1.5pt}
}
\vspace{-1.5 cm}
\begin{center}
   \section*{\ovalbox{\Large{SECTION A}}}  
\end{center}

\fontsize{15}{18}\selectfont
\begin{questions}
\pointformat{}
\question[4] The set of intelligent students in a class is :

\begin{tasks}(2)
\task A null set 
\task A singleton set
\task A finite set
\task Not a well defined collection
\end{tasks} 

\thispagestyle{empty}
\question[4] If $n(U)=700$, $n(A)=200$, $n(B)=300$ and $n(A \cap B)=100$, then value of $n(A^c \cap B^c)$ is :

\begin{tasks}(2)
\task $400$
\task $600$
\task $300$
\task $200$
\end{tasks}




\end{questions}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `\maketitle` inputs seem to have errors so I commented it out.  As to the issue at hand, I define

```
\newcommand\correct[1]{#1}
\let\svprintanswers\printanswers
\renewcommand\printanswers{\def\correct{\textcolor{red}}\svprintanswers}
```

and then, for the answers which are the correct ones, I use the syntax `\correct{<correct answer>}`, as in

```
\begin{tasks}(2)
\task \correct{A null set}
\task A singleton set
\task A finite set
\task Not a well defined collection
\end{tasks}
```

Then, when `\printanswers` is active, it prints in red.  Otherwise, it prints in the prevailing color.

```
\documentclass[a4peper,12pt,addpoints]{exam}
\date{}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage[top=0.6in, bottom=1in, left=0.6in, right=0.55in]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancybox}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{tasks}
\usepackage{mathpazo}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}
\usepackage{anyfontsize}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage[ddmmyyyy]{datetime}
\usepackage{multicol,adjustbox}
\usepackage{cellspace}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage{color, colortbl}
\title{\vspace{-1.6cm}\bfseries\huge \fbox{\fbox{DAILY PRACTICE PROBLEM}} \\[3mm]
    \Large  \fbox{XYZ}\\[5mm] \hline\hline \vspace{0.3 cm}
    \normalsize  MM: 50 \hfill Duration : 30 minutes \hfill  DPP 1 \vspace{0.3 cm} \hline \hline
}
\settasks{label=(\Alph*), label-width=2em}
\renewcommand{\solutiontitle}{\noindent\textbf{Answer:}\enspace}
\SolutionEmphasis{\color{red}}

\newcommand\correct[1]{#1}
\let\svprintanswers\printanswers
\renewcommand\printanswers{\def\correct{\textcolor{red}}\svprintanswers}

\printanswers


\begin{document}
%\maketitle% HAS ERRORS IN INPUT

\vspace{-2.8 cm}

\begin{center}

 \subsection*{\Large{IMPORTANT INSTRUCTIONS}}   
\end{center}
\rule[2ex]{\textwidth}{2pt}
\begin{enumerate}\singlespacing \small
 \item Section A contains TEN objective type question having only one option correct. Each question carries $4$ marks.
 \item  Section B contains FIVE True/False questions. Each question carries $2$ marks.
 \item In section A, $4$ marks will be awarded for marking correct answer, $-1$ for marking incorrect answer and $0$ marks for not marking the answer.
 \item There is no negative marking in section B .

\end{enumerate}
\rule[2ex]{\textwidth}{1.5pt}

{ \fontsize{12}{14.4}\selectfont
\begin{center}
\cellwidth{0.3cm}
\hqword{\textbf{Question:}}
\hpword{\textbf{Marks Allotted:}}
\hsword{\textbf{Marks Obtained:}}
\gradetable[h][questions]
\end{center}
\rule[2ex]{\textwidth}{1.5pt}
}
\vspace{-1.5 cm}
\begin{center}
   \section*{\ovalbox{\Large{SECTION A}}}  
\end{center}

\fontsize{15}{18}\selectfont
\begin{questions}
\pointformat{}
\question[4] The set of intelligent students in a class is :

\begin{tasks}(2)
\task \correct{A null set}
\task A singleton set
\task A finite set
\task Not a well defined collection
\end{tasks} 

\thispagestyle{empty}
\question[4] If $n(U)=700$, $n(A)=200$, $n(B)=300$ and $n(A \cap B)=100$, then value of $n(A^c \cap B^c)$ is :

\begin{tasks}(2)
\task $400$
\task $600$
\task \correct{$300$}
\task $200$
\end{tasks}




\end{questions}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If, as indicated, you also want it bold, then the `\renewcommand` could have been defined as

```
\renewcommand\printanswers{%
  \def\correct##1{\textcolor{red}{\bfseries##1}}%
  \svprintanswers}
```

However, answers in math mode, such as question 2, will not be bolded.